# Fetching value for display:column title in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, displaytag, ognl

I am working on a display table version 1.2 on Struts 2 application. I am having problem with fetching value for "titleKey" in my display table column.

```jsp
<display:column property="propertyName" titleKey="common.property" />
```

But here Title key is not able to display the value from properties file.
`common.property` is available in application resources and if I do

```jsp
<s:text name="common.property"/>
```

It properly displays the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EL expression for the `title` of the column. Before that the text for the title could be set to the value stack. EL expressions in Struts2 have access to the value stack when searching for variables.

```jsp
<s:set var="commonProperty" value="%{getText('common.property')}"/>
<display:column property="propertyName" title="${commonProperty}" />
```